# Multiplier custom option

Tags: custom-options, simple-product, custom-prices

I need to add a custom option to a simple product which will be number of pages.
This needs to get multiplied rather than added to other fields.

Example:

1. Black and white (€0.03) or Colour (€0.15)
2. Paper quality: Say €0.02

After the user chooses black and white and the paper quality, this adds up to (€0.03+ €0.02) €0.05 which needs to be multiplied by the number of pages (another custom field) that the document being uploaded (in another custom field) contains.

Is this possible in any way?

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is not possible per default, but should be possible by creating an own option. At least it's possible to implement custom pricing for a custom option (which will override that one of specified in the product settings)